# Replace only a couple of instances of string in string C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, substring

Using the C#'s `String.Replace` function replaces all instances of `A` with `B` found in the string `s` if I write this: `string c = s.Replace(A, B);`

I would like to replace only several instances of `A` with `B`.

So, for example, for `s=jjjk-A--iii-A---A---A` (Which has 4 instances of `A`), I would like to replace only the first two instances with `B` so that eventually I get `jjjk-B--iii-B---A---A`.

I can do it manually. Is there any `C#` function which does that?

Comment: Is it always prepended with `jjjk-` and `iii-` ?

Comment: Not at all....It was just a random string I wrote....There's no specific order..